# make a Jfile Chooser Query

Tags: java, mysql

I used a query which is used to import a CSV file into a database:

```
DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\TT (4).csv' INTO TABLE incident FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  (id_incident, status, vendor, priority, criticality_tt, title, description, affected_ci, affected_service, assignee, assignment_group, reassignment_count, open_time, close_time, outage_start, reassignment_time, outage_end, impact, solution, assignment_manager_name, assign_deptmgr, opened_by, closed_by, closure_code, update_action, last_updated_by);
```

I want to make this operation with `JFileChooser` so I tried with this code :

```
JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser(); 
fc.showOpenDialog(this);
File f=fc.getSelectedFile();
String path=f.getAbsolutePath();
try
{ 
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
int len=(int)f.length(); 
        java.sql.PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '?' INTO TABLE incident FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'  (id_incident, status, vendor, priority, criticality_tt, title, description, affected_ci, affected_service, assignee, assignment_group, reassignment_count, open_time, close_time, outage_start, reassignment_time, outage_end, impact, solution, assignment_manager_name, assign_deptmgr, opened_by, closed_by, closure_code, update_action, last_updated_by)");
ps1.setBinaryStream(1, fin, len); 
int status =ps1.executeUpdate();
if(status > 0) 
{ 
    j1.setText("Successfully inserted in DB"); 
}
else
{ 
        j2.setText(" not inserted!"); 
        } 
}
catch(Exception e)
{System.out.println(e);
}
```

It gives no error and no result.

Comment: I believe such statement can't be executed as PreparedSatetement, especially with FileInputStream as parameter. Try to execute it as static Statement.

Answer (score -1):

This will Help you in your task.

```
public YOUR-METHOD(){
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath()));
            List myEntries = reader.readAll();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

And [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugka_yKT-k4) some Video Tutorial You can Learn.

Comment: Where is *table* method?

Comment: @agad : its not necessary for the purpose of this question, i had copy-paste mine logic. `myEntries` contains all the records, do what you need..

Comment: I believe, that problem is with **loading data to db**, not reading the file. I don't see big difference between your code (*CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath()));*) and his code (*FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);*), except of checking if the file was really selected (*if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)*).

Comment: i used your video agad but a problem appeared: java.lang.arrayIndexOutOfBounds:0